# sqlfluff not aligning create table constraints when multiple constraints are present

Tags: postgresql, sqlfluff

I am using sqlfluff to format my postgres migrations and my queries.
In the company I work at, we align our `create table` types and constraints.

When creating tables, the alignment between column constraints seems to fail when multiple constraints exist (i.e. `not null unique` vs `not null`).
The documentation is quite opaque for table creation statements, so I have been stuck on this issue for a while.

When asked to align constraints, sqlfluff seems to align constraints on the last constraint (`unique` on `not null unique`), which I do not want - I want to align based on the first constraint (the `not`).

To use a toy example, the ideal formatting would be

```
create table tbl (
    foo   text not null,
    fooey int  not null,
    bar   text not null unique
);
```

However, I seem to get the following:

```
create table tbl (
    foo   text          not null,
    fooey int           not null,
    bar   text not null unique
);
```

I have found that when I insert a `primary key generated always as identity`, sqlfluff then seems to align everything on the `generated` and entirely ignore alignment for multiple constraints (?!)

```
create table tbl (
    id    text primary key generated always as identity,
    foo   text             not null,
    fooey int              not null,
    bar   text not null unique
);
```

Is this a bug or intended behaviour?

I've scoured the web for anyone else with this issue, yet I have not found any path to fixing it.
My .sqlfluff is provided below, please help! Thank you.

```
[sqlfluff]
templater = jinja
dialect = postgres
max_line_length = 0
exclude_rules = None
processes = 1


[sqlfluff:indentation]
tab_space_size = 4
indent_unit = space
indented_using_on = true
indented_on_contents = true
allow_implicit_indents = true
indented_joins = true
indented_ctes = true

[sqlfluff:layout:type:column]
spacing_before = align
align_within = statement
align_scope = file

[sqlfluff:layout:type:column_definition]
spacing_before = align
align_within = statement
align_scope = file

[sqlfluff:layout:type:column_constraint_segment]
spacing_before = align
align_within = statement
align_scope = file

[sqlfluff:layout:type:data_type]
spacing_before = align
align_within = statement
align_scope = file
```

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed a bug, and has since been resolved in [PR 5238](https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff/pull/5238). There are some other issues with alignment for the Postgres dialect at the moment (for instance [square brackets](https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff/issues/5328)), but it appears to be improving quickly.